# How to write this Flutter code more efficiently?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As you can see in first part I'm checking that a certain value contains in a document from Firestore and returns a boolean value. Now I'm calling that function in a build and based on that return value I'm changing a chip color (second part).

Now the problem is maybe because I'm calling it in a build function so its being called continuously and on that build and it costing me a ton of reads in Firestore or maybe the function is inefficient. How can I write this more efficiently?

```
checkAtt(String name, id , date) async{
   var ref = _db.collection('subjects').document(id).collection('Att').document(date);
   var docref = await ref.get();
      return docref.data.containsKey(name)
        ?true
        :false;
  }
```

```
 class PresentChip extends StatefulWidget {
  final candidate;
  PresentChip(
    this.candidate, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PresentChipState createState() => _PresentChipState();
}

class _PresentChipState extends State<PresentChip> {
  var isSelected = false;
  var c = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SelectSub selectSub = Provider.of<SelectSub>(context);
    final Date date = Provider.of<Date>(context);

  db.checkAtt(widget.candidate, selectSub.selectsub, date.datenew).then((result){
    print(result);
    setState(() {
     c = result; 
    });
  }); 

       return Container(
      child: ChoiceChip(
        label: Text('Present'),
        selected: isSelected,
        onSelected: (selected) {
          db.gibAtt(
              widget.candidate, selectSub.selectsub, date.datenew.toString());
          setState(() {
            isSelected = selected;
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: !c ?Colors.red :Colors.green ,
        selectedColor: !c ?Colors.red :Colors.green ,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: you should post your images in the question, not in the comments of the question

Comment: @Durdu like that ?

Comment: You should add the code directly, not as images.

Comment: @Durdu ok....edited

Comment: I've edited this question. Previously it was phrased as "would anyone like to do some free work", I've now changed it so the emphasis is how you, the author of the post, can achieve the desired outcome. The difference may be subtle, but it may explain the four downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to read once from firestore, you need a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```
return Container(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: db.checkAtt(widget.candidate, selectSub.selectsub, date.datenew),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData)
      return ChoiceChip(
        ...
        backgroundColor: !snapshot.data ?Colors.red :Colors.green,
        selectedColor: !snapshot.data ?Colors.red :Colors.green,
      );

      //Return another widget if the future has no data
      return Text('Future has no data');
    }
  )
);
```

If you need your UI to react to changes from firestore, use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

You can remove the following bloc from your build method:

```
db.checkAtt(widget.candidate, selectSub.selectsub, date.datenew).then((result){
  print(result);
  setState(() {
   c = result; 
  });
});
```